# undefined reference to 'vtable of derived_class'

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, undefined-reference, vtable

I've seen all the other answers to this error but i've tried all I could find and still nothing worked.

here's my code:

```
class Train{
    protected:
        string myID;
        int myCap;
        int myPass;
        char myType;
    public:
        Train(string str,int num): myID(str), myCap(num){myPass=0;}
        virtual ~Train(){};
        string getmyID(){return myID;}
        int getmyCap(){return myCap;}
        char getmyType(){return myType;}
        virtual void showTrainInfo()=0;
        virtual int getCost(string,string)=0;

        virtual bool operator== (const string)=0;
};



class STrain: public Train{
    public:
        STrain(string str, int num): Train(str,num){myType='S';}
        ~STrain(){cout<<"Deleted Train:"<<myID<<endl;}
        void showTrainInfo(){
            cout << "Train ID: " << this->myID << endl;
            cout << "Train Capacity: " << this->myCap << endl;
            cout << "Train Type: " << this->myType << endl;
        }
        int getCost(string origin, string dest);
        bool operator== (const string a){
        bool compare = false;
            if(myID.compare(a) == 0)
                compare = true;

        return compare;
        }
};
```

The error is in the derived function STrain. I've also tried defining my virtual destructor in the base class Train but it still gives the same error.

Other errors I've seen, the virtual function in Train was not defined and was solved by adding `{}` to the virtual function but as you can see, it doesn't work for me. Any suggestions or explanations to possibly why this happens?

Comment: Do you have a definition for `STrain::getCost` somewhere?

Comment: not yet though i did try commenting all the `int getCost` out and it didn't solve anything. i defined `STrain::getCost` and it looked like it took care of it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

After adding some furniture to reproduce your error, I can make it go away by defining the `STrain::getCost` function:

```
 int STrain::getCost(string origin, string dest) { return 0; }
```

Then it compiles successfully.

If you are still having trouble , please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as otherwise we are just guessing about what you have in the rest of your code.

Comment: you're right, the error did go away. Do you happen to know why? i tried removing the function all together but it didn't work so i had thought that `getCost` wasn't the one causing the error. thanks for the help!

Comment: @ChelseaTalay yes, since it is a pure virtual function  in the base class, you have to provide a body for it in any derived class that you create instances of (even if you don't call the function). The error message is a bit cryptic.